# jQuery UI - adding HTML to an element when item is DROPPED

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have some nicely working jQuery UI drag and drop functionality. Being rather new to both jQuery and Javascript in general I have a problem. When my item is dropped inside the DROPPABLE area I would like to change the element.

My element is a textbox and when it is dropped I would like to add:

1. "on click" functionality. The "on click" should open a modal that allows the 
   user to make the textbox required or not.
2. I would like to add a "remove" button to the textbox. This remove-button 
   should       delete the textbox from the DROPPABLE area.
3. Set an ID to the textbox

The project is made in ASP.Net/C# so I have the power of that if needed.

I hope I am making myself clear on what I'm looking for. This all needs to fire on the "drop" event... Thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".drag li").each(function () {
                $(this).draggable({
                    helper: 'clone',
                    cursor: 'move'
                });
            });

            $(".droppable").droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(ui.draggable).clone(true, true).appendTo(this);
                }
            }).sortable({
                connectWith: ".droppable",
                items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
                sort: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Create New Form - Big Mouth Messenger</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.js" integrity="sha256-wPFJNIFlVY49B+CuAIrDr932XSb6Jk3J1M22M3E2ylQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
                <td id="dragbox" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; margin-left: 10px; vertical-align: top">
                    <ul class="drag" style="list-style-type: none; width:100%; padding:20px 0px; margin:10px auto;">
                        <li class="draggable" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px"><div style="margin-right: 25px"><h1 id="header">Headline</h1></div></li>
                        <li class="draggable" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px"><div style="margin-right: 25px"><input id="textbox" type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 300px" /></div></li>
                        <li class="draggable" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px"><div style="margin-right: 25px"><input type="checkbox" value="Checkbox" /> Checkbox</div></li>
                        <li class="draggable" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px"><div style="margin-right: 25px"><input type="radio" value="Radiobutton" /> Radiobutton</div></li>
                        <li class="draggable" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px"><div style="margin-right: 25px"><select class="form-control" style="width: 300px"><option>item 1</option><option>item 2</option></select></div></li>
                        <li class="draggable" style="list-style-type: none; margin: 5px"><div style="margin-right: 25px"><input type="button" value="Button" class="form-control" style="width: 100px" /></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td id="dropbox" style="width: 50%; height: 100%; border: 2px solid gray; vertical-align: top">
                    <ul  class="droppable" style="list-style-type: none; width:100%; height: 100%; margin:10px auto;"> 

                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: please share your code...

Comment: Code is in... added as a jsfiddle. It seems dropping is not working in the fiddle, but it is working on my local server. Please try it and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what I can see in your html is, element being dragged in not a `text` but `li`. In all your `li`'s, you have different elements. So What you ned to do is to find the correct element from you li and then do the rest on drop.

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    var li = $(ui.draggable).clone();
    var textBox = $(li).find("input[type='text']");
    $(textBox).attr("id", "yourIdHere"); // #3 add Id to textBox
    if ($(textBox).length > 0) {
        $(textBox).click(function () {
            // #1: write the code to handle the click here
        });
    }
    //#2: Add button like following
    var button = ["<button type='button' onclick='removeText(" +this+");'>Remove</button>"];
    li.append(button);
    li.appendTo(this);
}
```

and then define the following function-

```
function removeText(li) {
    //write the code to find and remove `textbox` from `li`
}
```

Update the above code according to your scenario and things should be working.

Code may have some mistakes as I just typed it and did not run. But it will definitely give you a good idea.

Comment: Ty thanks, I'll try to implement this solution tomorrow.